# Need to get the ids of Multiple items

Tags: apex, visualforce, debugging

```
 <apex:pageblock >    
       <Apex:pageblockButtons >
         <apex:commandButton value="Process" action="{!savetemp}" rerender="thebtn" immediate="true">
             <apex:param name="actionProcess" value="actionProcess" assignTo="{!processids}"/>
          </apex:commandbutton>   
       </Apex:pageblockButtons>  
 <apex:pageblocktable value="{!convalues}" var="con" columns="9">        
            <apex:column headerValue="Sno:">
               {!con.viewContact__c}
             </apex:column>          
             <apex:column headervalue="Action">   

                 <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!con.id}" styleclass="checkbox{!rowNum}"   />
             </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Order Number">
                <apex:outputtext value="{!con.OrderNumber__c}" />
             </apex:column>
             <apex:column headerValue="First Name">
                 <apex:outputfield value="{!con.First_Name__c}"/>
             </apex:column>
  </apex:pageblocktable>  
</apex:pageBlock>
```

My class

```
public class tempView {
list<Temporary_contact__c> conValues;
public list<Temporary_contact__c> getconValues() {
     conValues = [select id,First_Name__c,Last_Name__c,Email__c,Installment__c,Check_temp__c,Map_Contact__c,OrderNumber__c,Recurring__c from Temporary_contact__c];
        system.debug('connn'+conValues.size());
       for(integer i=0;i<conValues.size();i++){
            conValues[i].viewContact__c = string.valueOf(i);
        } 
        return conValues;
}
 public tempView(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
}
  public void savetemp(){
         processids = apexPages.currentpage().getParameters().get('id');
         system.debug('iddddddd'+processids); //here I'm getting the null value
         string[] chklst = processids.split('--');
         list<string> checklist = new list<string>();
         for(string checkstr:chklst){
             checklist.add(checkstr);         
         }
             system.debug('checkkkkk'+checklist);
    }
}
```

How can I get the id of the selected objects.Any help on this pls
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of a wrapper class can be useful here . You can have a look at this link :

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class

The scenario should work for you.

You dont have to use apex param to pass the record ids if you implement this with the help of wrapper class . If you look at the page mentioned above , you can iterate through the wrapper list and just check which records have been selected like :

```
for(cContact cCon: getContacts()) {
   if(cCon.selected == true) {
    selectedContacts.add(cCon.con);
   }
}
```

Comment: Can I use apex:param for this?????

Comment: Edited the answer :)